# Display taxes twice or more

Tags: magento-1.9

This is very strange. Magento displays (but does not charge, just displays) some taxes twice or more after payment. It's not at the summary in the checkout, it's in order, in invoices and my account. So after the payment.

There is no logic, for example number of taxes displaying not depends of number of products ... I'me coming crazy o0   !

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In your Admin go to System -> Configuration -> (Sales)Tax -> Shopping Cart Display Settings there are a lot of settings that control that.

When I am building Canadian stores I usually change the first three to "Excluding Tax", Include Tax in Grand Total to "No" and "Display Full Tax Summary" and "Display Zero Tax Subtotal" to "Yes".

For the section titled "Orders, Invoices, Creditmemos Display Settings" I set everything to either "Excluding Tax" or "Yes".

This should give you the regular Tax displays that Quebec residents expect. Be aware that this setting can be overridden at the Store View level so if you have an English and French store, the settings may be different there. Below is a screenshot of that settings page.

[image: Quebec tax settings]